# Linq to Sql First() Not work

Tags: sql, linq, lambda

This :

```
DbModal.SM_SYS_Globals.First(x => x.ObjectValue.Contains("To"))
```

Has Error :

```
Expression cannot contain lambda expressions
```

Comment: might be duplicate ques of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469408/htmlagilitypack-expression-cannot-contain-lambda-expressions

Answer (score 0):

Use the following instead

DbModal.SM_SYS_Globals.Where(x => x.ObjectValue.Contains("To")).First()